# looping in perl

Tags: perl

I am writing this loop where in the initializing i am intializing using a variable and not a absolute value.Why doesn't the value change? Or is it not allowed in the for loop?

```
enter code here
 for($i = $one, $i > $top_level,$i--)
    {  
      print $i,"\n";
      print "One is:",$one,"\n";
     }
```

Why can't i assign $i= $one.
The variable $one keeps changing so thats the reason why i declared $i to $one.When i print the individual values of the variables the values are correct, its just that in the for loop the value is not being assigned.

Comment: I'm don't understand what you are getting at here. It might help if you told us what `$one`, `$top_level` and the output you want are, along with that "the value" means — the value of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What on earth are you trying to do? Is this a normal 'for' loop or are you trying to do something exotic. Note use of semicolon, NOT comma. Using a comma in any loop does something completely different: runs each bit of code each time.

Normally it would be:

```
$one = 1;
for($i = $one; $i > $top_level;$i--)
{  
  print $i,"\n";
  print "One is:",$one,"\n";
 }
```

It is Perl right?

Answer (score 6):

Use semicolons, not commas.

```
for($i = $one; $i > $top_level; $i--)
{  
    print $i,"\n";
    print "One is:",$one,"\n";
}
```

[Avoid C-Style loops in perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=723825), if possible.

```
for my $i (reverse $top_level..$one) {
    print $i,"\n";
    print "One is:",$one,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The separator inside the for() statement is ";", not ",".

Answer (score 3):

You've accidentally stumbled on using for with a list, by using commas instead of semi-colons. Watch what happens when you add a third print statement:

```
    print "\$_=[$_]\n";
```

with `$one` as 1, I get:

```
$_=[0]
...
$_=[]
...
$_=[1]
```

And that is because there are *three* items in the list. First of all what you wanted to do, would have looked like this:

```
for my $i ( $one..( $top_level - 1 )) {
```

In this loop, `$i` is set to each member of the range and then the loop is executed. If we don't suppy the variable, perl assigns it to `$_`.

```
for ( $one..( $top_level - 1 )) {
```

And perl does not wait to compile the list, so before it ever execute the first time it goes through all the terms.

```
$i = $one; 
# push actual $i returned by expression $i = $one
push @a, $i;                  
# result = [ $i=1 ]
# push boolean false => ''
push @a, ( $i > $top_level ); 
# result = [ $i=1, '' ]
# push the return of $i--, NOT $i
push @a, ( $i );              
# result = [ $i=1, '', 1 ]
# decrement $i
$i--;                         
# result = [ $i=0, '', 1 ]
```

You can find this out using a TIE-ed scalar:

```
package Monitored;
sub TIESCALAR {
    my ( $class, $name, $value ) = @_;
    return bless { name => $name, value => $value }, $class;
}

sub FETCH {
    my $self = shift;
    Carp::carp "Reading \$$self->{name}...";
    return $self->{value};
}

sub STORE { 
    my $self = shift;
    my $value = shift;
    Carp::carp "Storing \$$self->{name}=${\(defined( $value ) ? $value : 'undef')} ";
    $self->{value} = $value;
}
```

And this initialization in the mainline:

```
my $one       = 1;
tie my $i,         'Monitored', 'i';
tie my $top_level, 'Monitored', 'top_level', 5;
for($i = $one, $i > $top_level,$i--) # line 30
    {  
      print "*LOOP*\n";
      #print "\$i=$i\n"; <-- commented out to reduce noise
      #print "\$one=$one\n";
      print "\$_=[$_]\n";  # line 35
     }
```

Then in running the loop the output is:

```
Storing $i=1 at - line 30
Reading $top_level... at - line 30
Reading $i... at - line 30
Reading $i... at - line 30
Reading $i... at - line 30
Storing $i=0  at - line 30
*LOOP*
Reading $i... at - line 35
$_=[0]
*LOOP*
$_=[]
*LOOP*
$_=[1]
```

Note that only one time, at line 35, do we access `$i` after the looping starts.